# How to achieve this animated Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-animated, react-native-scrollview, react-native-animatable

I want to Flatlist item's size smaller than previous item and when i start scrolling the item size has to be change according position of item list when it comes to first position it should be display item size with actual size of first item of the list.

This is design which i want to implement

[image: Design image]

Comment: I think this could help you https://youtu.be/NiFdK-s6OP8

Comment: you can use Animated.View.